# install4j multiple instances under the same process in Linux

Tags: install4j

We're looking into install4j version 7, and specifically its new feature where when launching in Linux, it can run the new instance under the same process.

In testing this, we noticed that the splash screen shows when each new instance is launched.  The new instance run correctly under the same process, but the splash screen is still shown.

This does not happen in Windows, when the second instance is launched, the splash does not show.

Is there a setting that we're missing?

Or is there a reason for this different behavior?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On Windows, the generated launcher is a native executable. Before creating the JVM it can check if there already is a process or not.

On Linux, the generated launcher is a shell script that cannot perform the check reliably. The check is done in Java code using features from NIO2. The splash screen is displayed by the java binary before any Java code can run. This means that the splash screen unavoidable on Linux.